# Spring PushGateway pushes metrics without an instance tag

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, prometheus-pushgateway

Here's my config:

```
management.metrics.export.prometheus=true
management.metrics.export.prometheus.pushgateway.enabled=true
management.metrics.export.prometheus.pushgateway.push-rate=1m
management.metrics.export.prometheus.pushgateway.base-url=<IP>:9091
management.metrics.export.prometheus.pushgateway.job=myjob
```

Looking at the `<IP>:9091/metrics` endpoint of PushGateway, I see the following tags:

```
{instance="",job="myjob"}
```

Ideally, I'd like that "instance" will be the ip address and port of the running service.

It is worth mentioning I used `honor_labels: true` in the Promethoues conf.

How can I set (automatically if possible) the instance tag?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following - setting it as key-value in the grouping-key map - should do the trick:

```
management.metrics.export.prometheus.pushgateway.grouping-key.instance=${hostname:localhost}:${server.port}
```

You don't necessarily need to set the "job" property as it is derived from `spring.application.name` and then a fallback. See [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.1.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/export/prometheus/PrometheusMetricsExportAutoConfiguration.java#L125).

Comment: Thanks. I'll mention for future readers that I eventually created `PrometheusPushGatewayManager` bean myself in order to set *instance* tag to `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()`.

Comment: "instance" property has to be set to see the value in the metrics